# iPadOS: Stop Safari from allowing restricted sites

Tags: ipad, safari, screen-time

I have two iPads set up for children, and I'm using Screen Time to restrict the websites that they can visit to a white list of allowed sites.

When a 'forbidden' website is accessed, both iPads give a page saying: "Restricted Site. You cannot browse this page."

One iPad is running iPadOS 12, and this works well. The other is running iPadOS 14.4, and this one also gives a button on the page, saying "Allow Website". Tapping this button allows the website with no password or PIN.

This makes it 'childsplay' to override the restriction list. Is there any way of improving this?

[image]